# How to initialize a string to "" when using auto-implemented property

Tags: c#

How can I set a string to "" when using an auto-implemented property like:

```
public string Blah {get; set;}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You indicated that you are "using it for a strongly typed view, so I don't have a constructor for it even". If you don't have access to a constructor, it sounds like maybe you shouldn't use an auto-implemented property.

Comment: After thinking about this further, I don't understand why you don't have access to a constructor. Isn't this property defined in the model? The model *can* have a constructor. I don't think this has anything to do with whether or not you're using a strongly-typed view, but I could be wrong.

Answer (score 10):

When you use an [automatic property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384054.aspx) like this, the default value for the property type is the value, unless you initialize it elsewhere, like in the constructor:

```
public class Person
{
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public Person()
    {
        Name = string.Empty;
    }
}
```

However, if your automatic property has a public setter (as shown above), then you're still open to someone else setting Name to `null`, which may cause you some problems.

I can see two solutions, depending on your context.

First, change your automatic property to a private setter:

```
public class Person
{
    public string Name { get; private set; }

    public Person()
    {
        Name = string.Empty;
    }
}
```

This prevents anyone else from changing the property at all. If this isn't convenient, you could use a full property instead, and leverage the [`??`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173224.aspx) ([null-coalescing](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173224.aspx)) operator to prevent nulls:

```
public class Person
{
    public string Name 
    { 
        get { return mName; }
        set { mName = value ?? string.empty; }
    }

    public Person()
    {
        Name = string.Empty;
    }

    private string mName;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the property ...

```
Blah = String.Empty;
```

<strike>... but I'm pretty sure that's default(string) anyway.</strike>  Sorry, default(string) is indeed null.  But setting the property works just fine. :)

Comment: string defaults to null and not empty string. Please correct your answer.

Answer (score 2):

Set all your defaults in a (parameterless) constructor...

```
public MyClass()
{
    Blah = string.Empty;
}
```

Comment: i'm using it for a strongly typed view, so I don't have a constructor for it even.

Comment: Can you elaborate a bit? ... if you implemented the property as `public string Blah { get; set; }`, then surely you also have enough control to add some constructor to the class this propery exists on?

Comment: You CAN have a constructor on a view model... if indeed you are doing this in .NET MVC.

Answer (score 2):

if you lack a constructor perhaps consider doing it another way

```
  private string Blah = "";

  public string Bleh {
     get { return Blah;  }
     set { Blah = value; }
  }
```

Answer (score 2):

Just to remind that initializing a string to "" is not a good practice. A string should remain null until getting a value.

Comment: It is not good practice because null and "" are distinct meaningful values, and there are things other than the constructor that can set strings to null. Strings can be null, you cannot change that, your code has to be able to deal with this fact.

Comment: Isn't a good practice because performance and business logic.

Performance: strings are immutable and therefore very inefficient if you need to change it once it's constructed. After you initialize a string even with "", when you set a new value, you are instancing another string.

Business logic: Consider the example of having a column in your table that allow nulls. So, null is a state that needs to be consider. Null or "" are different states with different meanings, and should be logic to work with both in your application.

Comment: not that i completely disagree, but food for thought: if someone submits an HTML form, how do you know whether this is supposed to be `""` (String.Empty) or `null`??  When I'm dealing with web apps, I often make no distinction between the two. In other areas and layers, I do. You would have to know why the OP wants to do this in the first place I suppose.

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```cs
public string Blah { get; set; } = string.Empty;
```

As far as 2023 and NET Core 7.0

Answer (score 0):

Just in the interests of challenging your assumptions, why is it a problem to have a null? In some circumstances it's quite a meaningful state. When using that property of your class you can always use the string.IsNullOrEmpty(p.Name) test.